# How to create URL sub directories in Freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I inherited a project from another developer using Apache Freemarker, a tool we haven't used before.

I cannot figure out how to create a subdirectory that users can access.  For PHP I would create an index file in the filesystem (e.g. /my-directory/index.php) and the user would access the URL at http://www.example.come/my-directory/

How can I do that with Freemarker?  I've looked into the documentation for areas like  in web.xml, and creating the subdirectory with index.ftl file in the filestructure itself, but no luck.

What am I missing?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the web application framework you are using (Spring MVC, Struts, etc.), not on FreeMarker. FreeMarker is just an MVC View technology, so at least in well designed frameworks you don't visit templates directly. You visit "actions" (or whatever they are called in the concrete framework), and the actions contain most of the business logic, and at the end they chose a template a to render the result with.

Comment: Thanks.  I see lots of `import org.spring.blahblahblah`, so I'm guessing its Spring.  I'll read up on the documentation (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) and see what I can find.  No wonder I wasn't finding anything in the freemarker documentation. :-)